# New inode when mounting new file system

Tags: linux, filesystems, vfs

**Does kernel really create any new inode when some file system gets mounted** on some directory of root file system? I don't expect it to create as there is no new files are being created. Is there some soft link being created? I've read that superblock operation reads field of "newly created inode" from mounted file system.

Comment: inodes belong to filesystems, when you mount a new filesystem on a dir, you "bring" latter's inode on former's.

Comment: So does it mean only inode of root directory of file system being mounted gets added to root file system? Thanks